# Android Permission always being denied

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-location

```
package com.example.suyashadhikary.address;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;    import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

LocationManager locationManager;
String provider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        Log.i(" Location", "Denied: ");

        return;
    }
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       Log.i(" Location", "Denied: "); 
    }
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    Log.i("latitude",String.valueOf(latitude));


}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}
```

}

I basically want the latitude and longitude , but I think the permission is always being denied. I have added the permissions in the manifest file like so:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

but while looking at the logcat I am getting Location: Denied, which means the permission is not being granted. Do i need to override something here?

Comment: No, but you need to request the runtime permissions. Simply calling `checkSelfPermission()` is insufficient. You need to call `requestPermissions()` if you do not have the permissions you seek, then implement `onRequestPermissionsResult()` to find out if the user granted them to you or not.

This is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Comment: is this on Marshmallow (23) or above?  If so then you need to request the permissions.

Comment: public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {